# count and print same number of occurences in String in java

Tags: java, string, dictionary

Need help to sort and efficiently print the same occurrences of the words in the below string.

Here is the occurrence for the string: `{java=2, occurences=1, program=3, sample=1, the=2}`

Expected output:

java=2,occurences=1,sample=1,the=2

```
String str = "sample program java program the occurences the java program";
String[] inputstr = str.split(" ");
TreeMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(String input: inputstr) {
    if(map.containsKey(input)) {
        int value = map.get(input);
        map.put(input,value+1);
    } else {
        map.put(input,1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The only difference I can see between expected and actual result is that you don't seem to expect the word "program" to be counted. Why should it not be counted?

Comment: Please post your program's output.

Comment: It should print only those words whose occurence is same . Say if the string is "learning java and java" . here the occurence is java=2, learning=1, and=1   and count 1 is repeating so the output should be leaning=1 and=1

Comment: yes for sorting order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert the above code to a single line using java-8

```
Map<String, Long> countMap = Arrays.stream(inputstr)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::toString, Collectors.counting()));
```

EDIT :

We need to find values in the map that have an occurrence of more than one. Achieved so using the following code :

```
// inversed the map using "google-guava.jar"
Multimap<Long, String> inverseMap = HashMultimap.create();
for (Entry<String, Long> entry : countMap .entrySet()) {
    inverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}

for (Entry<Long, Collection<String>> entry : inverseMap.asMap().entrySet()) {
    // split the values into an array
    Object[] split = entry.getValue().stream().toArray(); 
    if (split != null && split.length > 1) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(split[j]) + " : " 
                             + countMap.get(String.valueOf(split[j])));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should print only those words whose occurence is same . Say if the string is "learning java and java" . here the occurence is java=2, learning=1, and=1   and count 1 is repeating so the output should be leaning=1 and=1

Comment: That's easy. Iterate over this `countMap` and print out keys that have a value equal to 1!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply nicholas. We should print only when the occurence is duplicate.. For eg. 1. String= "Test and Test "    expected output: <None>                Eg2: String="Time and Tide"          expected output: time=1 , and=1,tide=1      eg3:String="read read and and" expected output: read=2 and=2

Comment: This comment contradicts your previous one (:/). If you want duplicates then just change the `e.getValue() == 1` --> `e.getValue() > 1`

Comment: Iam sorry if iam not clear. I mean duplicate number of occurences count. If the word occurence count is duplicate then print all the words for that duplicate occurence. Eg:String= "Test and Test "  in this Test=2 and =1  no duplicate occurence count so the output is blank <NONE>

Comment: How is that possible? Isn't 'Test' repeated twice? So shouldn't that be printed?

Comment: In that sentence, the counts are 2,1   here the occurence are not duplicate so no output <BLANK>  If the occurence are duplicate say for example for this string'Test and Test and'   Test=2, and=2   here both the occurence are 2,2 so print those output: Test=2, and=2

Comment: @krthk : I've included my solution as an edit, hope it helps!